# For how many $b\in \{1,\dots,a\}$ is $1,11,111,\ldots$ (in base $b$) a complete residue system mod $a$? For what fraction of $a$ is the answer 1?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Disclaimer: I am definitely a number theory novice (the vague memory of one college course comprises the totality of my knowledge on the subject). As such, I apologize in advance for any mistakes or oversights.

This question is based on a [blog post](https://nickel62.blogspot.com/2019/04/problem-time-many-ones-deduction.html) I wrote, ending in a question I wasn't able to solve. The description there is a little bit circuitous, so I will try to describe things more succinctly here.

For any integers $k,b>0$, let $c(k,b)=11\dots11_b=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}b^i$. For any integer $a>0$, let $R(a)$ denote the number of $b\in \{1,\dots,a\}$ such that $\{c(1,b),\dots,c(a,b)\}$ is a complete residue system (mod $a$). In particular, this requires that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so we have $1\leq R(a)\leq \varphi(a)$. So a natural question seems to be, when are these bounds achieved?

On one end, we have $R(a)=\varphi(a)$ if and only if $a=2$. But the question of when $R(a)=1$ seems to be harder. We can show that $R(p)=1$ for any prime $p$ (this follows from Problem 3 in my post), so there are infinitely many minimizing values. But I'm curious about what fraction of positive integers (if it converges) satisfy $R(a)=1$. More specifically, does the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\#\big(R^{-1}(1)\cap \{1,\dots,n\}\big)}{n}$$
converge? If so, what does it converge to? Using Matlab, I was able to calculate up to $n=5000$ and it seems to tend towards about $71\%$. But I have no intuition as to why, or if it will continue…

Comment: Not that such a limit can not exist between, but I would be very surprised if it was not $0$ or $1$. Although they do happen, it is rare to see limits based on the density in the natural numbers that hit some 'random' number other than $0$ or $1$. But who knows, it would be cool to find out it doesn't

Comment: You've noted that $\gcd(a,b)$ is required; we can also note that $\gcd(a,b-1)>1$ is required—if $\gcd(a,b-1)=1$, then $\{c(1,b),\dots,c(a,b)\}=\{\frac{b-1}{b-1},\frac{b^2-1}{b-1},\dots,\frac{b^a-1}{b-1}\}$ is a complete residue system if and only if $\{b-1,b^2-1,\dots,b^a-1\}$ is, if and only if $\{1,b,b^2,b^a\}$ is; but this would mean that the order of $b$ modulo $a$ is at least $a$, contradicting Euler's theorem that the order is at most $\phi(a)$ (we ignore $a=1$).

Comment: Emperically, it seems that if $\alpha$ is odd, then $R(\alpha)=R(2\alpha)=R(4\alpha)$ and that $R(2^k\alpha)=2^{k-2}R(\alpha)$ for all $k\ge2$ (indeed, the exact set of valid $b$s seems predictable as we increase the power of $2$). In particular, $R^{-1}(1)={S,2S,4S}$ where $S=R^{-1}(1)\cap(2\Bbb N-1)$, the density of which is $\frac74$ times the density of $S$ itself.

Comment: Finally, emperically it seems that $S$ is precisely the set of odd non-squarefree numbers, that is, the set of odd numbers divisible by the square of an odd prime. (In other words, $R^{-1}(a)$ seems to be the set of integers not divisible by $8$ or by the square of an odd prime.) Indeed the set of valid $b$ seems somewhat predictable from those square factors; it even seems that $R(a) = a/\rho(a)$ for odd $a$, where $\rho(a)$ is the "radical" of $a$, namely the product of all distinct primes dividing $a$.

Comment: If all of these observations are correct, then the density of $S$ (the set of odd squarefree numbers) is equal to to $4/\pi^2$, and thus the density of $R^{-1}$ is equal to $7/\pi^2$. Since $\pi^2$ is just less than $10$, this is a very good match to the 71% you observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg Martin's very helpful comments have led me to an answer.

Let's write $\mathscr R(a)$ for the set of $b\in \{1,\dots,a\}$ such that $\{c(1,b),\dots,c(a,b)\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $a$. Then $R(a)=\#\mathscr R(a)$. If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, note that $\mathscr R(ab)$ is identified with $\mathscr R(a)\times \mathscr R(b)$ under the identification $\mathbb Z/ab\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ of the Chinese remainder theorem. It follows that $R$ is a multiplicative function. It remains to determine the value of $R$ on prime powers. Using induction and the binomial theorem, we can see that: if $p$ is an odd prime and $k>0$, then $b\in \mathscr R(p^k)$ if and only if $b\equiv 1\,\,( \text{mod } p)$; if $k>1$, then $b\in \mathscr R(2^k)$ if and only if $b\equiv 1\,\,(\text{mod }4)$. From this, Greg Martin's notes follows at once, showing that indeed $R^{-1}(1)$ has density $7/\pi^2$.

I have written a [blog post](https://nickel62.blogspot.com/2020/05/many-ones-deduction-part-ii.html) that proves these results in detail.